# Change ordering in MVC3 Index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Would like to have clickable column titles eg click on TagCode once and it orders by that, and again it reverses.  Same for Number.

Using MVC3/Razor and LightSpeed (ORM).

I know that a grid eg http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/ may be the way forward.  But as I don't need paging or filtering, I'd like to keep it simple for now.

**Problem** Is there a simple example of code (maybe with an up/down icon) that would help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dave

Sorry, I missed your main point in my first answer
If you want to implement sorting using pure MVC3,
I can do that with following steps

1. list action method passing sortcolumn and order info to viewpage via ViewBag

   Html Helper method to build actionlink with column ordering display

   list viewpage calling the helper method

[I uploaded source code here](http://sites.google.com/site/supremeware/src/blog/TagManager.zip)

---

**List action method**

```
        public ActionResult Index(string sortColumn, bool? asc)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortColumn))
            sortColumn = "Number";

        asc = asc ?? true;
        SortDirection sortDirection = asc == true ? SortDirection.Ascending : SortDirection.Descending;
        var query = _service.GetTags().OrderBy(sortColumn, sortDirection);

        return View(query);
    }
```

**Html helper method**

```
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkWithColumnOrder(this HtmlHelper helper,
        string columnName,string action,string currentColumn,bool currentOrder)
    {
        object routeValues;
        object htmlAttributes = null;
        if (columnName == currentColumn)
        {
            routeValues = new { sortColumn = columnName, asc = !currentOrder };
            htmlAttributes = new { @class = currentOrder ? "sort_asc" : "sort_desc" };
        }
        else
        {
            routeValues = new { sortColumn = columnName };
        }

        return helper.ActionLink(columnName, action, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

**List View page** 
...
@Html.ActionLinkWithColumnOrder("TagCode", "Index", (string)ViewBag.sortColumn, (bool)ViewBag.asc)
...
@Html.ActionLinkWithColumnOrder("Number", "Index", (string)ViewBag.sortColumn, (bool)ViewBag.asc)

**Happy Mvcing!**

Sangsu PARK (http://supremeware.blogspot.com)

Comment: @Sansu - many thanks that is ideal.  What I love about MVC is that there are no bits of magic happening.. this is perfect.  I'll probably have to write more code, but its easy to figure out when I come back to it.

Comment: I wrote http://www.programgood.net/2011/04/08/SortingColumnsInMVC3.aspx which shows how to do dynamic queries using LightSpeed.  Thanks Ivan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423728/mvccontrib-grid-sorting

Comment: @Dave. If you can use the orderby extension in mvccontrib.sorting, the code can be more simple.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave

How about using mvccontribgrid with ordering only as follows:

[image]

IMO, Using mvccontribgrid may bring more simple code.
This is controller code for example

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AlbumService _service;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _service = new AlbumService();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions gridSortOptions)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel<Album>()
        {
            DefaultSort = "AlbumId",
            GridSortOptions = gridSortOptions,
            List = _service.GetAlbums()
            .OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction),
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var album = _service.GetAlbum(id);
        ViewBag.RouteDicForList = Request.QueryString.ToRouteDic(); 
        return View(album);
    }
}
```

I attached simple sort function source code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/supremeware/src/blog/MvcMusicStore.Simple.zip) with simple service & EF4.

Also, I posted full featured mvccontrib grid filtering & paging article [here](http://supremeware.blogspot.com/2011/03/genericviewmodel-based-grid.html).

Comment: Many thanks @Sangsu  I'm actually looking for something super simple.. but this looks like a good next step.