# MvcContrib Grid Sorting

Tags: linq, mvccontrib

Am testing out MvcContrib's grid for sorting.

Am using LightSpeed as my ORM

**Problem:** getting compile error on:  listOfRfidTags = ...

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions sort)
        {
            IEnumerable<RfidTag> listOfRfidTags = uow.RfidTags;
            if(sort.Column != null) {
                listOfRfidTags = listOfRfidTags.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
            }
            ViewData["sort"] = sort;
            return View(listOfRfidTags);
        }
```

view:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>{
    column.For(a => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = a.Id })).Named("Edit");
    column.For(a => a.TagCode).Named("TagCode").Sortable(true);
    column.For(a => a.Number);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OrderBy extension method takes a delegate for getting the sort key, not a column and direction.  So this line:

```
listOfRfidTags = listOfRfidTags.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
```

needs to look something like this:

```
listOfRfidTags = listOfRfidTags.OrderBy(r => r.SomeProperty);
```

(or OrderByDescending depending on the sort.Direction).  The trouble is that SomeProperty can't be determined at compile time because you want it to come from sort.Column.  This means that if you want to use LINQ then you'll probably need to use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) or Reflection to extract the property you want to sort on e.g.

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(RfidTag).GetProperty(sort.Column);
listOfRfidTags = listOfRfidTags.OrderBy(r => property.GetValue(r));
```

However, since you are using LightSpeed as your ORM, you can bypass LINQ and use the core API, which *does* allow dynamic column names:

```
Order order = Order.By(sort.Column);
if (sort.Direction == SortDirection.Descending))
  order = order.Descending();
IList<RfidTag> listOfRfidTags = uow.Find<RfidTag>(new Query { Order = order });
```

This has the side benefit that the sorting will happen on the database instead of in the Web application.

Comment: This is great.  I wrote http://www.programgood.net/2011/04/08/SortingColumnsInMVC3.aspx based off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417220/change-ordering-in-mvc3-index-view

Answer (score 11):

You are getting this compiling error because you are trying to use an *OrderBy* extension method that is only defined in **MvcContrib** and not in System.Linq.

In order to fix it, you just need to use the following line:

```
using MvcContrib.Sorting;
```

And then you can use the *OrderBy* method as in your original code:

```
listOfRfidTags = listOfRfidTags.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
```

Although *itowlson* answer works, he just reimplements what the *OrderBy* extension method in *MvcContrib* already does (see [SortExtensions.cs](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/459484756843#src/MVCContrib/Sorting/SortExtensions.cs)).

Comment: I had exact same problem and this fixed it for me

Comment: Yes, why reinvent the wheel.